# I'm working with PySpark and trying to run a Spark SQL query on a DataFrame. Here's the code I'm using:

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm working with PySpark and trying to run a Spark SQL query on a DataFrame.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT industry, value 
    FROM data 
    WHERE value > 200 
    AND industry != "total"
""").show()
```

Error -

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist.
```

Comment: Did you try putting total within single quotes? Like  `AND industry != 'total'`

Answer (score 0):

spark.sql("""
SELECT industry, value
FROM data
WHERE value > 200
AND industry != 'total'
""").show()